# How to display 2 AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer on screen simultaneously?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

Is it possible to show 2 UIViews/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer showing what the camera can see in real-time at the same time? They would both need to be perfectly synchronized.

thanks,
Henri

Comment: possible duplicate of [AVCaptureSession with multiple previews](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543075/avcapturesession-with-multiple-previews)