# Using AVFoundation and RNCamera preview at the same time

Tags: react-native

I am building a real-time video processor for iOS and react native. I would like to use the [RNCamera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) component to just show a live video view, while at the same time using AVFoundation in a native module.

In a swift native module, I am capturing video by starting a capture session (in the constructor) and implementing the `captureOutput` delegate method:

```
self.captureSession.startRunning()

func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection)
```

In my React code, I am just creating a RNCamera component:

```
<RNCamera>...</RNCamera>
```

Right away, I'm noticing that as soon as the RNCamera kicks in, the `captureOutput` callback is no longer called.

## Question

I would like to know if it is somehow possible to achieve what I'm trying to do. Am I missing something simple? If so, how would I do that? If not, what are the limiting factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically if you look at `RNCamera` implementation here: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/dea33716aa00201136e16f8b3d2ecaf4bdc622f3/ios/RN/RNCamera.m#L57. They are initiating a new `AVCaptureSession` object and using the same camera type as the one your swift module is using. I think that causes your AVCaptureSession to be paused and therefore you don't receive new events with `captureOutput` method.

However, you can still have multiple outputs/previews from this suggested source (it requires you to fork the RNCamera lib and add your own custom implementation):

Multiple video output: [AVCaptureSession with multiple previews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16543075/avcapturesession-with-multiple-previews) (The part 2. Manually Rendering SampleBuffer might be interesting for you)